# XML basic style options

Tags: xml, coding-style

So I'm returning xml from a web service and I get this message in the browser (firefox)

> This XML file does not appear to have
>   any style information associated with
>   it. The document tree is shown below.

Is this a simple fix by just passing a CSS style sheet? or is the a preferred way of styling XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way of styling XML is XSLT. And if I'm not mistaken, XSL stylesheets are what the message actually refers to.

Without any further info, I cannot suggest anything specific. If you show some of your XML and say how it should be represented, I could get you started with a basic XSL stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to style XML with **CSS** and with **XSLT**.  Most browsers will apply both **CSS** and **XSLT** stylesheets and render the results, when the proper processing instruction is provided in the XML.

**To apply CSS to an XML file add a processing instruction like this:**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="my-style.css" ?>
```

**To apply XSLT to an XML file add a processing instruction like this:**

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="my-transform.xsl" ?>
```

If your styling requirements are more display and decoration of the XML content, rather than transformation, then CSS styling might be easier.

Check out this W3C page: [**How to add style to XML**](http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML)